# Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime when importing by gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to use reflections in my android project, but I'm getting

```
kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection 
implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin- 
reflect.jar in the classpath
```

The weird part is than it's not working only when I'm importing kotlin-reflect by gradle. If I add the .jar manually to libs directory, everything works just fine.
The jar is from the exact same maven page from where I took the compile line

project level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    //I tried many variants of adding the library - the commented lines

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.11"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.11"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11'

    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.3.11"
    //compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: '1.3.11'
    //compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Simple test I'm willing to run

```
class Reflections {

    class A(val property: Int)

    @Test
    fun javaGetter() {
        println(
            A::property.getter.returnType
        )
    }

}
```

I've checked other questions on Stack, but no luck with answers in those.

What am I doing wrong, what am I missing?

Comment: This works fine, are you running the test in Idea or command line?

Comment: Try using `api` instead of `implementation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to plug it in at the top level gradle file e.g

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: This works, should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get notifications about your comment since today o.O 
Gradle is a bit different today on Android, but maybe somebody will still benefit on it. Here ya go